# Unable to set up single sign on for enterprise application in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We installed an enterprise application through the Azure AD App Gallery. But when we try to config the Single Sign-on, it keeps saying:

> The single sign-on configuration is not available for this application
> in the Enterprise applications experience. HubSpot is a multi-tenant
> application and the application is owned by another tenant.

Do we need to change some settings to allow the setup of Single sign-on?
We followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/hubspot-tutorial#add-hubspot-from-the-gallery) but are now stuck on "Configure Azure AD SSO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When added the hubspot  application from Azure AD Enterprise application gallery like below ,you should be able to see if SSO setting is available or not and the ways it can be supported for sso.(*Here i can be able to use SAML based SSO, or linked SSO*)

[image]

Then you should be able to edit the saml configuration

[image]

For me when I search the hubspot app created in app registrations, its under supported account type of `my organization only`.

[image]

Please check if the App is registered and  added as Multi-Tenant App in your case and users have to use login for particular tenant instead of `common` to avoid error.

> Also user accounts need to be pre-provisioned into HubSpot prior to
> sign-in .

**Reference:**
[Sign in with My Apps portal and Azure AD SSO in multi tenants application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679987/sign-in-with-my-apps-portal-and-azure-ad-sso-in-multi-tenants-application)

Comment: After checking the setup, we were missing the Hubspot entry in the "App Registrations". We added Hubspot a second time to our Enterprise Applications and now everthing works.  We added Hubspot the first time in november 2021.